# Draggable - set helper if condition is true

Tags: jquery, draggable, helper

Is it possible to set the helper in jquery draggable only if (let's say) the control key is pressed when you start dragging? I tried this:

```
start: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.helper = !cntrlIsPressed ? "original" : $("<div></div>").text($(this).text()).css({    "background": $(this).css("background"), "padding": $(this).css("padding") }).attr({"data-predmetId": $(this).attr("data-predmetId"), "data-predmetNaziv": $(this).attr("data-predmetNaziv")}).addClass("helper");
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, [`helper`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) option accept a function:

> A function that will return a DOMElement to use while dragging.

here you can check if the CTRL is pressed and act accordingly, keep in mind to return a jQuery/DOM element.

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        helper: function (evt) {
           return !evt.ctrlKey ? $(this) : $("<div>Demooooooo</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mt5Mr/